# Rails yield and content_for in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, partial-views, yield

I've got used to use `content_for` and `yield` for my views in order to set the page title and other neat stuff, related to view rendering.

And now I got stuck with next scheme: LAYOUT -> VIEW (edit.html.erb) -> PARTIAL (_main.html). That is - view contains a partial.

If I define `content_for :view_content_title, "Hello World"` in the partial, it IS accessible in the LAYOUT, but it is **NOT** in the VIEW - `content_for?(:view_content_title)`

Why ? What should I do about it ?

Comment: Do you render partial in the view before or after you check for content existence?

Comment: @khustochka I render it AFTER. The idea was to print out the title first and then the partial content.

Comment: Then I think I am correct. Until the partial is rendered, its code is not executed, e.g. content not set.

Comment: So you're question paraphrased is, the `content_for` block in a partial is propagated all the way up to the layout, but why it isn't accessible to a yield in the view?

Comment: I found some answers here: http://stevechanin.blogspot.com/2009/11/clearing-out-content-in-contentfor.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I found out why. Rails renders the view in a linear way. It renders the view before partial, then a partial, then the rest of the view. I tested that if you call `content_for?` or render content in a view AFTER rendering the partial - it is OK, if before - content is not present.

And layout is rendered AFTER the view, that is why at that moment content is already available, because the view and the partial is already rendered e.g. directives executed.

Comment: Yes. I've got the same results. If I put the yield after rendering the partial - it works, but otherwise - it doesn't. 

Any ideas, how could I achieve the behavior I wanted ?

Comment: Just not using `content_for`? Plenty of ways depending on what you want to render. Just simply putting title in the view. Setting instance variable in the controller. Using i18n engine.

Comment: That's the thing I was trying to avoid - CONTROLLER. :(

Comment: It depends of how various the title can be. If it is just Hello World, just type it in :) If it is blog post title, render it with something like `<%= @post.title %>`. If title content is itself some rich HTML, consider using separate partial for the title.

Answer (score 1):

One possible workaround is that layouts do have access to **:locals**, so you can do something like this:

**view_file.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: "my_partial", layout:"my_layout", locals:{:title=>"Best Answer Ever"} %>
```

**_my_layout.html.erb**

```
<H1> <%= title %> </H1>
<%= yield %>
```

**_my_partial.html.erb**

```
All your content goes here, and this partial also has access to locals if you want to use them.
```

This will yield:

```
<H1>Best Answer Ever</H1>
All your content goes here, and this partial also has access to locals if you want to use them.
```